# CERT_HAS_EXPIRED error when a POST request is made through npm request module on Nodejs, Certificate is valid however

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

when i call a POST endpoint from npm request module in my nodejs app (hosted on elasticbeanstalk aws). it gives me CERT_HAS_EXPIRED error, however my ssl certificate is valid and works perfectly when someone visit our site.

this started happening randomly 3 days earlier.

does anyone know what can be done? to fix it?

```
{ Error: certificate has expired
     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1088:38)
     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38) code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED' }
```

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you specifically mean *"when i call a POST endpoint from npm request module in my nodejs app."* Do you mean your Node.js application code on the server is making a POST to an external resource?

Comment: Check the link; https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT

Comment: @SalahiHalilAltıncı how do i verify that i have the same problem, my certs are generated by amazon, so not sure if it has anything to do with sectigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So @Salahi's comment was correct, support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT

it wasn't a problem on our end, but one of the root certificates expired for the services we were trying to access, and therefore were receiving this error.